# What is wrong with my break command? It's not working

Tags: python-3.6

For school we're to create a program that accepts inputs from the user as positive numbers and continues to add them up till the required -1 input for the break command. When I run it I'm getting the while loop to work just fine entering 2,2,2 then -1 which should do the break command at that point then state 6 and the end print prompt. However, when I input -1 it just keeps asking for inputs and the break command isn't executing.

```
total = 0
print("Enter the value '-1' to exit \n")

while True:
    if total == '-1':
        break
    total += float(input('Enter a positive number: '))
print(total)
print('End of program')
```

At one point I had the break command working correctly but had an issue with the combination of the inputs. Once I fixed that issue I began having the break issue and cannot figure it out, been at it for at least 3 hours and driving myself mad. Book has terrible examples. And I've exhausted google searchers.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

total is a float and you are comparing it to a string.

```
total = 0
while True:
    value = input("enter a value:")
    if value == "-1":
        break
    total += float(value)
```